# How to call rest api in python which is present in other system

Tags: python

Please provide me any example and installation process in python.

Example required is: Python file should available in localhost and server file should available in other system or remote server.So when I run the python file then Api should call for return json from the server file which is present in remote system

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Python file:                                                                                                         
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/api/say_name', methods=['POST'])
def say_name():
    json = request.get_json()
    first_name = json['first_name']
    last_name = json['last_name']
    return jsonify(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.147', debug=True)

Comment: this python should hit rest api in other system for json response how can I do that

Comment: @user5963022, can you please edit the code in your comment in more readable format, please use the code option provided in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question seems a bit unclear but what I infer is that you want a REST API which returns a JSON response after running a business logic on the request params/body.

You might want to have a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ to start with writing a REST API with `django-rest-framework`.

Comment: I required a example simple login page which hits the http url available in remote system from there I should get the response

Comment: Yes, you will have to create a REST API, deploy it and then consume it. Read the link mentioned in the answer to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your server is responding with the data, you can use python `requests` to send a call to your API and retrieve the data.

```
import requests

datatosend = {"first_name": "bleh", "last_name": "bleh"}
send = requests.post("http//your_url", data=datatosend)

print(send.content)
```

If you want a web form to post the data, please do some google search, you would get one.